# Azure: what could be the cause of the error "Unable to edit or replace deployment"?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-deployment, azure-rm-template

When I recreate my VM I got the following error:

```
Problem occurred during request to Azure services. Cloud provider details: Unable to edit or replace deployment 'VM-Name': previous deployment from '8/20/2019 6:20:33 AM' is still active (expiration time is '8/27/2019 5:17:41 AM'). Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy for usage details.
```

Help me please to understand. 
What could be the cause of the error ?

---

**UPDATED:**

This deployment has not been started previously.
Prior to this, errors were received during creation:

```
Azure is not available now. Please Try again later
```

There were several such errors one at a time and then I got that error related to:

```
Unable to edit or replace deployment
```

My assumptions about this.
Tell me, am I right or not ?

I launched the image, then after some time I recreated it.
Creation began, but at that moment the connection with Azure was lost.
Then, when the connection was restored, we tried to make a deployment that was not removed in the previous attempt (because there was no connection with Azure).
As a result, we got such an error.

Does this theory make sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

exactly what it says, there is another deployment with the same name going on at this time, either change the name of the deployment you are trying to queue or wait for the other deployment to finish\fail

Comment: I updated my question. Do you think this has a place to be?

Comment: I'm not sure what the actual question is, if you wait max of 2 hours deployment will fail and you can restart it. or you can go to the portal and cancel it (or using the sdk)

Comment: I understand you, thank you.
I would also like to know at least an approximate reason why this could happen.

Comment: well, this will ALWAYS happen as you try to create a deployment with the same name as the one that already exists and is running. if you try to create a deployment with the same anem and it is failed or completed it will overwrite it

Comment: they think they did not have it. your guess is wrong. the error posted by the op originally clearly indicates what is the fault. in reality deployments can hang for more than 2 hours (and can be created by somebody else in the company). please assume a person who works 60h\week on azure stuff and has about 3k upvotes in the tag knows a thing or two about azure.

Comment: Just to add my 2c on this, I ran into this recently as I do reuse the deployment name and the deployment was hung with a 500 Gateway Timeout. Canceling and re-running the job gave the "DeploymentActive" error. Solution was to delete the deployment and start fresh.

Answer (score 12):

This can also occur if you use Bicep templates for your ARM deployement and multiple modules or resources in the template have the same name:

```
module fooModule '../modules/foo.bicep' = {
   name: 'foo'
}

module barModule '../modules/bar.bicep' = {
   name: 'foo'
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Darrell, this was the answer for me. I'd moved code from the main bicep template to a dedicated module. Problem was, the code in the new module also called a module and had the same value for the "name" property

Answer (score 2):

Go to azure portal. Choose the resource group and click 'Deployments' under the setting.  Find running deployment, cancel or restart deployment.

Comment: This resolved my issue. This should be the right answer.

Comment: No, this is not the right answer and tells nothing about the root cause nor why this is considered a fix (which it isn't). The above answers do that.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error initially pipeline was working but when retriggered pipeline took more time so i canceled the deployment and made a fresh rerun it encounters. i think i need wait until that deployment filed.

Comment: I think this qualifies as an answer, but you might want to polish it a little according to [answer] and maybe take the [tour].